# Threads in Linux

Tags: linux

I have gone through mostly all the questions on here regarding the topic of `Pthreads` in Linux but there is a basic doubt which remains unresolved for me:

It is mentioned in various responses that when we create a POSIX thread on Linux, there is a 1:1 mapping between user thread and kernel thread.

My doubt is when we use `pthread_create()` in Linux, is there 1 user thread and a corresponding unique kernel thread created implicitly *(i.e. a total of 2 threads, one of which is invisible to the user)*?

**OR**

There only one kernel thread created and there is nothing anymore in newer Linux kernels called a user thread?

Answer (score 2):

The NPTL (Native POSIX Thread Library) and the older LinuxThreads both use a 1:1 model, where each threads (or process) created by the user corresponds with one schedulable entity in the kernel.

However, you maybe confused by user-level threads, or [fibers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiber_%28computer_science%29), those are *threads of execution* created via calls like `makecontext()` and `swapcontext()` that have N:1 model, the kernel doesn't know about user-level threads and their scheduling is done in user-space.

Answer (score 0):

pthread_create() internally calls fork(), and vfork()/fork() internally calls clone(). So in most of the case it is 1:1 mapping.